# Short story about 3 alien hunters when mankind was still in tribes/prehistoric

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My dad told me about this short story he had read and it piqued my interest based on what he described.  It would have been a short story in a similar size of book to the *Commando War* stories in pictures comic, but as writing without pictures.

The story was around 3 alien hunters that would come to Earth when man was still in the an age just a bit more advanced than the Stone Age, and hunt man.  The story I am told was that during the story 2 out of the 3 hunters were beaten and the last of the alien hunters was trying to flee back to its drop pods to escape.  The best way I can visualise it from the description my dad gave me was *Predator*, but as a group of 3 during the Stone Age.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know how old your dad is, so what _year_ would it have been when he read this?

Comment: Would be around the late 1960's.  Cheers